# Does EntityManager.persist make the entity passed in managed, or does it simply create a managed entity, leaving the passed in object unchanged?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

we are having a little discussion at work here regarding the persist of a JPA EntityManager.

Assuming the following code:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
obj.setName("Lalala");
em.persist(obj);

// This is just an example to show that I intend on 
// using the obj instance after persisting.
em.flush();
System.out.println(obj.getId());
```

Now my understanding of persist is that it takes care of persisting obj but doesn't make obj managed. My colleagues claim that obj has now become managed which also is what the JavaDoc of the EntityManager claims.

My question now is: How can this be? In java, I can't think of any logic

```
Vehicle car = new Car();
try {
    car.fillInFuel(Fuel.TRUCK_DISEL);
    Asert.fail("filling in truck fuel into a car, should theow an exception.");
} catch(BadFuleException pfe) {
    // Handle this.
}

// Now call some sort of magic, converting my car into a truck. 
// (An unmanaged entity into a managed entity)
makeTruck(car);

// treat the car as a truck from here.
try {
    car.fillInFuel(Fuel.TRUCK_DISEL);
} catch(BadFuleException pfe) {
    Asert.fail("filling in truck fuel into a truck, should work.");
}
```

This might be a difference in how entities are made managed. I am used to using EclipseLink and my Colleagues are using Hibernate. In EclipseLink a call to persist doesn't make the entity instance I pass in to persist managed, it just takes care that the data is saved. If I want to continue working on a managed entity, I have to use merge instead.

```
if(!em.contains(obj)) {
    obj = em.merge(obj);
} else {
    em.persist(obj);
}
```

I know in EclipseLink a managed entity is different from an unmanaged entity, because the change tracking is done in the entity, in Hibernate however changes don't seem to be tracked at all.

So ... who's right? Is the interpretation of the Api-Docs for the EntityManager class simply different in EclipseLink and Hibernate? Is the one of EclipseLink even correct?

Chris

Comment: Reading section 3.2.2 of the JPA spec ought to clarify such things

Comment: EclipseLink does make the entity you call persist on managed.  Any changes to the entity after persist will be picked up as long as it wasn't serialized.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist%28java.lang.Object%29) is right (your colleagues are right).

I don't really understand the relationship of your example with Car/Vehicle with the managed state of the entities. But if you want to know how a JPA provider handles correctly that, than it is another question. A possible solution would be the following: on persist, copy the `orig` entity to the `copy` and on transaction commit, compare the `copy` entity with the managed `orig` entity. Of course there are also more complicated solutions (like AspectJ), although I don't think they are used in any of the JPA providers.

In order to test if Eclipse/Hibernate puts the entity in the managed state, try the following:

```
em.persist(obj);
if(!em.contains(obj)) {
    //print TRUE
} else {
   //print FALSE
}
```

> I know in EclipseLink a managed entity is different from an unmanaged
>   entity, because the change tracking is done in the entity, in
>   Hibernate however changes don't seem to be tracked at all.

In hibernate (or ANY JPA provider) the changes of a managed entity are also tracked (only that they are possibly flushed at another time). By tracked I mean, they are identified (earlier or later), and not necessarily tracked as they are made.

Also note that we speak here about changes of an entity made in the same class method  with a container-managed entity managers.

Comment: If changes are tracked the same way, how can the datastructures needed to keep track of these changes be added to an object that doesn't contain them? EclipseLink seems to create dynamic sub-classes of the original entity in memory and return instances of this type when calling merge, but not when calling persist (At least I'm pretty sure of that).

Comment: And I haven't found a way to access the set of changes of an entity in hibernate the way I was able to in EclipseLink (https://dev.c-ware.de/confluence/display/PUBLIC/JPA%3A+Find+out+which+properties+of+an+entity+have+changed). Having a look at the DB communication in Hibernate shows that the update of an entity seems to send all values (changed and unchanged), EclipseLink seems to update only the changed fields ... so I wouldn't say they handle things the same way.

Comment: I wanted to say tracked instead of handled. JPA does not force a provider to update only the changed fields, but it is sure, that all providers know what fields changed (changes are tracked, if entity is in the managed state).

Comment: I reformulated a bit my answer, in order to avoid confusions.

Comment: Think I'll have to whip up a small test when I'm at home.

Comment: Also, you could call `em.flush()` in order to see if any changes to your managed entity are persisted (also in EclipseLink).